# Dónde colocar otro tipo de hilo para que trabaje en conjunto junto a otro hilo

Tags: java, array, hilos

Tengo una clase principal con un array de hilos, los cuales se encargan de realizar modificaciones en los objetos del `arrayList` que paso por parámetro.

Ahora lo que necesito es otro hilo que se encargue de mostrar los datos de los objetos mientras se modifican, para poder ver la modificación. Obviamente el hilo que muestre datos irá más rápido que el que modifica.

```
public class Principal {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int ROOMS = 10;
        final int VIS = 7;
        final int GROUP = 7;
        Semaphore SEM = new Semaphore(GROUP);

        Visitante hiloVisitador[] = new Visitante[VIS];

        ArrayList<Room> sala = new ArrayList();

        for (int i = 0; i < ROOMS; i++) {

            String reg[] = new String[GROUP];
            for (int j = 0; j < GROUP; j++) {
                reg[j] = " ";
            }
            //array list de objetos
            sala.add(new Room(String.valueOf(i + 1), reg));
        }

        //array de hilos, se encargan de realizar modificaciones sobre los objetos de la lista
        for (int i = 0; i < VIS; i++) {
            hiloVisitador[i] = new Visitante(String.valueOf(i + 1), sala, SEM);
            hiloVisitador[i].start();
        }
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < VIS; i++) {
                hiloVisitador[i].join();
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

No sé donde colocar otro hilo, esa es mi pregunta.

Aclaro: No ocupo código para mi ejercicio (lo puedo desarrollar), sólo saber si es posible esto y si es así, dónde ponerlo, antes del hilo `Visitador`, después, etc.

Comment: no elimines una pregunta para realizarla nuevamente. En cambio, deberías editar la primera. Por favor tenelo en cuenta para el futuro, ya que podría considerarse como abuso. Y como comenté antes, por favor revisa el formato y la ortografía antes de publicar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Al parecer tienes una clase `Visitante` que extiende de `Thread` (denotado por `hiloVisitador[i].start()`). Tienes muchas maneras de agregar un hilo que haga otro tipo de trabajo con los objetos que tienes:

1. Crear una instancia anónima de `Runnable` que haga el trabajo y pasarla como parámetro en el constructor de `Thread`:

   ```
   Thread t = new Thread( () -> {
           //aquí va la definición del método run
       });
   t.start();
   ```
2. Crear una clase que implemente `Runnable` y pasar una instancia de esta clase en el constructor de la clase `Thread`:

   ```
   public class Mostrador implements Runnable {
       //definición de la clase...
       @Override
       public void run() {
           //lógica para mostrar los datos
       }
   }

   //dentro del método main

   Thread t = new Thread(new Mostrador(/*quizás pongas argumentos aquí*/));
   t.start();
   ```
3. Similar al anterior, pero que extienda de `Thread` (parecido a tu clase `Visitante`):

   ```
   public class Mostrador extends Thread {
       //definición de la clase...
       @Override
       public void run() {
           //lógica para mostrar los datos
       }
   }

   //dentro del método main

   Thread t = new Mostrador(/*quizás pongas argumentos aquí*/);
   t.start();
   ```

Puesto que ya tienes un arreglo de `Visitante`s, te recomendaría cambiarlo a un arreglo de `Thread`s puesto que no usas nada más de esa clase, y que el tamaño del arreglo permita 1 elemento más para contener esta nueva instancia de `Thread` creada manualmente:

```
Thread hilos[] = new Visitante[VIS+1];
for (int i = 0; i < VIS; i++) {
    hilos[i] = new Visitante(String.valueOf(i + 1), sala, SEM);
    hilos[i].start();
}
//descomentar de acuerdo a lo que escojas
//si usas la forma 1
//hilos[VIS] = new Thread( () -> {
//    });
//si usas la forma 2
//hilos[VIS] = new Thread(new Mostrador(/* argumentos */));
//si usas la forma 3
//hilos[VIS] = new Mostrador(/* argumentos */);
hilos[VIS].start();
try {
    for (int i = 0; i < VIS+1; i++) {
        hiloVisitador[i].join();
    }
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

> No ocupo código para mi ejercicio (lo puedo desarrollar), sólo saber si es posible esto y si es así, dónde ponerlo, antes del hilo Visitador, después, etc

Esto es irrelevante puesto que al ejecutar `Thread#start` no necesariamente un hilo va a comenzar su ejecución antes que otro. Esto lo decidirá el sistema operativo basado en el uso de los procesadores. Puedes poner el hilo antes o después de los elementos del arreglo, el resultado no debería afectar. Ahora, considera que si usas colecciones dentro de tus métodos p.e. `List`, `Map`, `Set`, entonces asegúrate de usar implementaciones que soporten concurrencia p.e. `ArrayList` **no** soporta concurrencia, en su lugar puedes usar `CopyOnWriteArrayList`, y así hay otras implementaciones para estas colecciones que puedes revisar en la documentación del paquete [`java.util.concurrent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html).

---

Ahora, esta solución no es tan elegante. En su lugar, recomendaría usar [`ExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) el cual va a gestionar los hilos por ti y te concentras solo en las tareas que deberían ejecutarse en paralelo.

Comment: Gracias Luiggi, y lo de "No ocupo codigo...." lo puse por calentura ya que uno anteriormente no entendió mi pregunta y dijo que yo lo que buscaba era que alguien me haga el codigo o mis tareas algo asi, y pues me calenté. es más le reporté. jejej.
Gracias Luiggi de nuevo eres un crack!